# Not able to access nginx default page using public IP

Tags: linux, security, azure, nginx, centos

I installed nginx on centos( on Microsoft Azure). I am able to get the default page of nginix on the localbox where I installed the nginx(centos on MS AZURE) by curling public IP but not able to curl from the public network. Can you guys please help on this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit `/etc/nginx/sites-available/proxy.conf`, there should be on the beginning `listen ...`, so try to put there

```
server {

    listen your-public-ip:80
    #rest of the file
}
```

And restart the service via `systemctl restart nginx`.